# ios Push Notifications not working if the user unintalled the app and then reinstalled it from the store?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I've encountered an unusual scenario where RegisterForRemoteNotifications not working. The scenario is as follows:

- user installs the app from the appstore for the first time the RegisterForRemoteNotifications works perfectly.
- user deletes the app from their device, also I delete the device info(token,ID,...etc) from my server.
- user reinstalls the app from the appstore again, here where I think the RegisterForRemoteNotifications is not working and user token would not be registered on my server.

Is that not accurate? What might be the reason behind that problem?

Comment: In this case the user must manually agree push-notifications in the preferences. Is the same behavior as regards the location.

Comment: @MirkoBrunner how would handel that? is that normal ??!

Comment: that's normal unfortunately. a good way is to perform an alert on the first run. so the user to point out that he must agree to the push service manually.

Comment: @MirkoBrunner i am not sure if that the best way to do it, according to apple docs, the method didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken should work every time the app run.
in my case it's working on ad-hoc and development but not the version on the store.. and thats so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the thing is the app register on my server successfully even if the user uninstalled the application and reinstall it again, so what i didn't know is that the Device ID changes every new install. So I was checking on the wrong IDs in my Database.